# Duvida de Cascade no SQL server com ASP.NET CORE 7 com EE e Identity

Tags: sql, asp.net, identity

Eu tenho um banco de dados "LocalWise" que tem as tabelas "Pessoa:IdentityUser" e outras como "Gerente, Documento, Endereco, PontoTuristico, Guia, Agenda e Itinerario" montados na seguinte ordem:
"Pessoa" que é Identity é pai de "Gerente" e "Guia";
"Guia" é pai de "Agenda", "Itinerario" e "PontoTuristico;
"Gerente é Pai de "Documento", "Endereco" e "PontoTuristico;
Aqui estão as casses:

```
public class Pessoa : IdentityUser
{
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime DataCadastro { get; set; }
}

public class Guia     {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string? UrlPhoto { get; set; }
    public string? Ativo { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Pessoa")]
    public string? PessoaId { get; set; }
    public Pessoa? Pessoa { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Gerente")]
    public int GerenteId { get; set; }
    public Gerente? Gerente { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Agenda")]
    public int AgendaId { get; set; }
    public Agenda? Agenda { get; set; }
}

 public class Agenda
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string? Segunda { get; set; }
    public string? Terca { get; set; }
    public string? Quarta { get; set; }
    public string? Quinta { get; set; }
    public string? Sexta { get; set; }
    public string? Sabado { get; set; }
    public string? Domingo { get; set; }
}

public class Itinerario
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string? Valor { get; set; }
    public TipoPasseio TipoPasseio { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Guia")]
    public int GuiaId { get; set; }
    public Guia? Guia { get; set; }
}

public class PontoTuristico
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string? Nome { get; set; }
    public string? Detalhes { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime DataCadastro { get; set; }
    public string? Valor { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Endereco")]
    public int EnderecoId { get; set; }
    public Endereco? Endereco { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Gerente")]
    public int GerenteId { get; set; }
    public Gerente? Gerente { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Guia")]
    public int GuiaId { get; set; }
    public Guia? Guia { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Itinerario")]
    public int ItinerarioId { get; set; }
    public Itinerario? Itinerario { get; set; }

}

public class Gerente
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string? RazaoSocial { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Endereco")]
    public int EnderecoId { get; set; }
    public Endereco? Endereco { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Pessoa")]
    public string? PessoaId { get; set; }
    public Pessoa? Pessoa { get; set; }
}

 public class Documento
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string? Documentos { get; set; }
    public string? URL { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Gerente")]
    public int GerenteId { get; set; }
    public Gerente? Gerente { get; set; }
}

public class Endereco
{
    //[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string? Logradouro { get; set; }
    public string? Numero { get; set; }
    public string? Bairro { get; set; }
    public string? Cidade { get; set; }
    public string? Cep { get; set; }
    public Estados Estado { get; set; }
}
```

As persistências são de dois tipos:
Para persistir em "Pessoa" que extends de -IdentityUser- eu uso userManager
e para persistir nas outras tabelas, que são EF. eu uso -context.Add(tabela)- e context.SaveChangesAsync()-, até ai tudo bem.
Agora, eu acho que por estar usando esses dois metodos o EF e o Identity não se entendem com as realações, por existir essas relações o comendo "onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade" do migration não parece estar funcionando.
Quando eu depuro o programa, ele roda, mas na hora de percsistir os dados ele da erro de "SqlException: Invalid object name 'AspNetUsers'.".
Pelo que parece as persistências do Identity não funcionam com as Persistências do EF e vice-versa.